# VirtualBox Linux black screen when display resolution set to 2560x1600

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, display, resolution

I am new to VirtualBox. I am running Linux (Debian 64-bit) on it. 
My host machine is a MacBook 2018 with a Retina display (2560 × 1600).

I start the VM and the default display resolution is 800 × 600. 
I tried to change the resolution inside Linux. 
Everything goes well. 
I switch to 1920 × 1440 and any other resolution under it. 
However, when I tried to set it to 2560 × 1600, it gets a black screen.

I am wondering how am I suppose to change the resolution to 2560 × 1600. 
Can anyone please help?

Comment: If you're using Virtualbox 6 or greater then change the display settings vga or svga or other options.

Comment: I am not sure where can I change the setting. I only find the graphics controller, which has choices of "None", "VMSVGA", "VBoxSVGA", "VBoxVGA"

Comment: I tried all the options. The default is VMSVGA, which I am having the problem with. If I choose. the "None", then start the machine, it is totally black.  The VBoxSVGA does not have a display resolution choice of 2560 × 1600. The VBoxVGA has the choice of 2560 × 1600. However, when choosing it, the screen froze. By the way, I have installed the guest addition.

Answer (score 13):

I had the exact same problem as yours. I found out that giving the virtual machine the maximum amount of video memory (128MB for me) allowed me to switch to 2560x1600 while using VMSVGA. Hope it solves it for you, too.

Comment: BTW: The setting is under Display > Screen; I would expect this to be in the System...

Comment: For me, 16MB wasn't enough for 2560x1440, while 32MB was sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Same as Simone's answer but I found that only 32 MB of video memory is enough for 2560 x 1440 monitor.

Video Memory: 32 MB

Graphics Controller: VMSVGA